# Regular expression repeitition: how to match expressions of variable lengths?

Tags: perl

Essentially, here's what I want to do:

```
if ($expression =~ /^\d{num}\w{num}$/)
{
     #doSomething
}
```

where `num` is not an identifier, but could stand for any integer greater than 0 (`\d` and `\w` were arbitrarily chosen).  I want to match a string iff it contains two groups of related characters, one group immediately followed by the other, and the number of characters in each group is the same.

For this example, `123abc` and `021202abcdef` would match, but `43abc` would not, neither would `12ab3c` or `1234acbcde`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don’t think of the string as growing from left to right, but rather from the outside in:

```
xy
x(xy)y
xx(xy)yy
```

Your regex would then be something like:

```
/^(x(?1)?y)$/
```

Where `(?1)` is a reference to the outer pair of parentheses. `?` makes it optional in order to give a “base case” of sorts to the recursive match. This is probably the simplest example of how regexes can be used to match [context-free grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_free_grammar)—though it’s generally easier to get right with a parser generator or parser combinator library.

Comment: Interesting.  Though perldoc.perl.org says "WARNING: This extended regular expression feature is considered experimental, and may be changed without notice."

Comment: You'd have to anchor it (say with `^..\z` or `(?<!x)..(?!y)`) to get the desired effect.

Comment: This makes sense. I've dealt with context-free grammars before, but I've never heard of `?1`.  Would `?2` give you the parent parentheses of `?1`?

Comment: Count Left Parentheses from the left.  By definition `?1` has no parent.  `?2` could be it's child or sibling....

Comment: @SteveP.: They’re numbered left to right by starting parenthesis, as are relative indices (`?+1`, `?-1`) which also use flat numbering. And of course the first open parenthesis to your left is also your parent if there are no intervening right parentheses.

Answer (score 4):

Well, there's

```
if ($expression =~ /^(\d+)([[:alpha:]]+)$/ && length($1)==length($2))
{
    #doSomething
}
```

A regex isn't always the best option.

Comment: I was thinking of chaining 2 matches using `m//gc` and `\G` but yours is way better.  You may want to nix the `^` and `$` as they may be more than the OP required.

Comment: @tjd: But if you don't have any anchors, then `"43abc"` would in fact match, since it contains `"3a"`.  I think it goes without saying that if you want to use this as a piece of a bigger regex, you take off the `^` and/or `$`.

Comment: `m/^(?>\d+)(\w+)$/` solves the problem that `"123a"` would match because `3` is a `\w`

Comment: Which means `\b` is a perfectly fine anchor.

Comment: Good catch.  The think-o in my brain-to-code translation was representing "letter" as `\w`.